# 2 Router wifi with different Gateway

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have 2 wifi router in different level floor in my home. Router A (upstair) has IP 192.168.0.*  and Router B (downstair) has IP 192.168.1.*

On many occasions my device on upstair connects to Router A wifi, but always get Router B IP (192.168.1.*). I don't understand this. This makes devices has no connectivity.
Note that, Router B wifi signal can't even reach upstair.

Can someone explain what's going on?

thanks
Mike

Comment: How are router A and router B connected to each other?

Comment: I don't know the terminology, it's through cable. Router A LAN port get into Router B WAN port.

Comment: Is it definitely that way LAN to WAN rather than LAN to LAN?  Do the routers have different SSIDs, is that how you know which one you are connected to?

Answer (score 0):

Your device is configured to automatically connect to a network with highest priority on the list of your Wireless Networks.

Possible explanation on your scenario is Router B is higher priority than Router A on your list of Wireless Networks. When your device sees that Router B is available, it automatically connects to Router B despite weak reception.

Solution:

1. Open Network and Sharing Center

   Run-> control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
2. Click Manage wireless networks
3. Select wireless network(Router A), and move it up the priority.
4. Right-click wireless network and click properties
   Uncheck "Connect automatically when this network is in range."
   Uncheck "Connect to a more preferred network if available."
5. Repeat step 4 for Router B

Now you have manual control which network to select.

Comment: It actually connect to Router A, but the device is getting router B IP address. This what confused me the most.

Comment: does your router have dhcp relay feature?

Comment: Yes...Router A has DHCP enabled

Comment: DHCP RELAY? I think DHCP request to router A is being forwarded to Router B

Comment: How to fix it? Router A using TP Link AC1750. I didn't see any option there, and I remember I set it up as usual. This is very random, some device get Router A IP, others get Router B IP.